# PHP access the log file

Tags: php, apache, iis-7

In asp I can access the log file in `\Inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1`
there something similar on php language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go in you `php.ini` file.

Activate the log with this:

```
display_errors = On
```

Also, you may want to check where the log is written:

```
error_log = /var/log/YourFileWithLog.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a log file in the `php.ini`